# Linq most efficient method

Tags: c#, linq

I have need to use Linq statement as following

```
      var data = db.tbl1
      .Where(w => clientIds == clientid && w.Source == source);
```

I have a dropdown where I am getting source from. The dropdown values are as such:

```
All
NewsPaper
Web
```

The thing is NewsPaper and Web are valid values for Source. All is not. 
All means that a record can be NewsPaper or Web.

If they choose All, how do I modify w.Source such that All means NewsPaper or Web.
I can do 2 seperate queries as shown below but rather not:

```
    if(source == "All")
    {
       var data = db.tbl1
      .Where(w => clientIds == clientid);
    }
    else
    {
       var data = db.tbl1
      .Where(w => clientIds == clientid && w.Source == source);
    }
```

I like to do it in 1 query as the query I have is actually more complicated than what is shown above.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@mattytommo answer is acceptable, but I prefer to break them out a bit. IMO a little more readable.

```
var data = db.tbl1.Where(w => clientIds == clientid);

if (source != "All")
    data = data.Where(w => w.Source == source);
```

Comment: This also takes advantage of the fact that LINQ expressions are lazy-evaluated.  You don't *have* to try to cram everything into one statement.

Comment: Good point, you can keep concatenating logic until you materialize the query into a `list` for example.

Comment: This is nicer, IMO, since it's more readable.  It's also more efficient in all cases, since you lose the extra compares.

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
var data = db.tbl1
  .Where(w => clientIds == clientid && (source == "All" || w.Source == source));
```